# What are the differences between these two ways of saving form information?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am learning how to use django forms and I was presented two ways to save information from a form. I tested the two and both work with validations, but I did not understand the difference between one and the other.

The first uses functions inherited from the models.Model class, using the function "objects.create(** form.cleaned_data)" and passing the form fields as a parameter.

In the example below, I instantiate the ProductForm class that inherits from 'forms.ModelForm' and use the 'cleaned_data' function to pass as a parameter.

```
def product_create_view(request):

    form = ProductForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            **Product.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)**
            form = ProductForm()

    data = {}
    data['form'] = form

    return render(request, 'products/product_create.html', data)
```

The second way instead of using the function 'objects.create(** dict)' uses form.save() directly.

```
def product_create_view(request):

    form = ProductForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            **form.save()**
            form = ProductForm()

    data = {}
    data['form'] = form

    return render(request, 'products/product_create.html', data)
```

I'd like to know there are differences between using form.save() and using Product.objects.create(** dict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call `form.save()` on a `ModelForm`. This is in general the easiest way to create and update a model. Note that `form.save()` in this case returns the saved instance, so you can write `product = form.save()` and do more stuff with the saved `product`.

If you create a form that subclasses the `Form` class, then it won't be linked to a specific model and you won't be able to save it. You have to construct your model from the form's `cleaned_data` parameters. You would have defined all the fields of your form manually to mimic the model, which is more work than for the `ModelForm`, where you can just give `fields` the list of fields of your model.

There's no difference in the end result, but generally a `ModelForm` and using `form.save()` is the preferred way since it's more readable and clear what you're doing.